# How to return not matches between two lists

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension, string-matching

I have two lists, each with several elements in them:

```
list_2 = ['https://josh.ucc.edu/just-go-grind-125/','https://josh.ucc.edu/thirty-minute-kayak-2/', 'https://josh.ucc.edu/fight-online-t-shirts-help-support-local-businesses/']
matchers = ['just-go-grind', 'thirty-minute']
```

I would like to use list comprehension to return not matches between the two lists. This is what I've tried:

```
not_matching = [s for s in list_2 if None(xs in s for xs in matchers)]
print(not_matching)
```

output:

```
not_matching = [s for s in list_2 if None(xs in s for xs in matchers)]]
                                                                       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I don't think I am using the list comprehension correctly but am unsure how to print a non-match, any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're looking for `any` built-in function  of python:

```
not_matching = [s for s in list_2 if not any(xs in s for xs in matchers)]
```

Output:

```
not_matching
['https://josh.ucc.edu/fight-online-t-shirts-help-support-local-businesses/']
```